# flexibly-sized circular images with CSS

Tags: html, image, css, responsive-design

I'm using these [very nice demos](http://webdesignerwall.com/demo/css3-image-styles/) to add some style to my images.

Unfortunately, the thing I've noticed with these demos is that you can't re-size the images. If you do then the images aren't centered properly.

Here's a screen shot to show you what I mean:

http://webdesignerwall.com/demo/css3-image-styles/

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/trpeters1/XkGuu/3/) for people to play with.

Can someone help figure out how to center these images such that each dog is entirely within view?

**UPDATE:** The developer of the demos recently updated his code to allow variable image size for many of the styles: http://webdesignerwall.com/demo/css3-image-styles-part-2/
Please note that circular images was *NOT* one of these updated styles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would like to play with `background-position` css property:

```
background-position: 0px 0px;
```

See the centered  [example](http://jsfiddle.net/XkGuu/4/).

You can also play with `background-size` css property:

```
background-size: 30px 30px;
```

See the zoomed in [example](http://jsfiddle.net/XkGuu/9/).

here's a more complete demonstration of many image styles at both 30px and 150px: http://jsfiddle.net/trpeters1/XkGuu/25/

Comment: -@CommunityDrivenBusiness thanks that is helpful, unfortunately if you change the size to 30px, then they are not centered again: http://jsfiddle.net/trpeters1/XkGuu/8/ thoughts on a reponsive/more flexible solution?

Comment: You can use background-size: 30px 30px in this case.

Comment: -@CommunityDrivenBusiness thanks yes, that works great! everyone who's interested please see this: http://jsfiddle.net/trpeters1/XkGuu/14/

Comment: You are welcome! I believe you will have a chance to help me back when I need that.